# Inserting values into array in assembly MASM32

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I'm having trouble figuring out how to put a value I currently have in register EAX into an array.

The basic function of this program is to take the dates array, convert them to unique numbers, BubbleSort them, and convert them back.

I put the values I find with "datetonum" into EAX, and I want to store those values I find into my array named `ra`.

I can't seem to figure out how to do something that.
Seems like it should be fairly simple?

Thanks in advance!

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.data
  dates  BYTE "23-JUL-2010", 0, "23-JAN-2010", 0, "23-JUL-2009", 0, "31-JUL-2012", 0, "05-MAR-2010", 0
  months BYTE "JAN",0,"FEB",0,"MAR",0,"APR",0,"MAY",0,"JUN",0,"JUL",0,"AUG",0,"SEP",0,"OCT",0,"NOV",0,"DEC",0
  nDates DWORD 4
  ra     DWORD 1,0,0,0,0

.code
start:
    lea  EAX, dates     ; create pointer to beginning of dates array
    push EAX
    call datetonum

    ;-------------------
    ;put value currently in EAX into array to be sorted
    ;-------------------
    print "Array to be sorted contents: "
    print chr$(13,10)


    lea ECX, ra
    mov [ECX + nDates], EAX
    print ra
    print chr$(13,10)
```

Here's the `datetonum` function

```
;param1 (date string) = address of 12 byte date
datetonum:
    enter 4, 0                    ; [EBP - 4] holds 4 byte temp variable
    mov  EBX, [EBP + 8]           ; pointer to entire date string
    lea  ESI, [EBX]               ; pointing to day part of date
    lea  EDI, [EBP - 4]           ; pointing to address of local variable to store day string
    mov  ECX, 2
    cld
    rep  movsb
    mov  EDX, 0
    mov  [EDI], EDX               ; add null terminator

    lea  EDX, [EBP - 4]
    mov  EAX, sval(EDX)           ; convert day string to int
    push EAX                      ; push EAX to stack


    ; extract month from date
    lea  ESI, [EBX + 3]           ; pointing to month part of date
    lea  EDI, [EBP - 4]           ; pointing to address of local variable to store month string
    mov  ECX, 3
    cld
    rep  movsb
    mov  EDX, 0
    mov  [EDI], EDX               ; add null terminator



    ; debug print of month string
    pushad
    lea  EDX, [EBP - 4]
    print EDX
    print chr$(9)                 ; print a tab character
    print chr$(13,10)
    popad

    ; find month number
    sub ESI, ESI
    lea EDX, [EBP - 4]
    mov EAX, [EDX]
    mov ECX, 12
search_top:
    lea EDX, [months + ESI * 4]
    mov EBX, [EDX]
    inc ESI
    cmp EAX, EBX
    loopne search_top

    mov EDX, ESI                    ; result is in ESI

    pop EAX                         ; pop EAX off the stack
    mov AH, DL                      ; copy the month int into AH
    push EAX                        ; push EAX to stack

    ; convert year chars to 2 byte int
    mov EBX, [EBP + 8]
    lea ESI, [EBX + 7]              ; pointing to year part of date
    lea EDI, [EBP - 4]              ; pointing to address of local variable to store year string
    mov ECX, 4
    cld
    rep movsb
    mov EDX, 0
    mov [EDI], EDX                  ; add null terminator

    lea EDX, [EBP - 4]
    mov EDX, sval(EDX)              ; convert year string to int

    pop EAX                         ; pop EAX off the stack
    mov EBX, EAX                    ; copy EAX (contains month in AH and day in AL) to EBX
    mov EAX, EDX                    ; copy year to EAX
    shl EAX, 16                     ; shift the year over to high 16 bits in EAX
    mov AX, BX                      ; copy the month and day into low 16 bits in EAX

    ;print EAX ; this crashes the proc
    print str$(EAX)
    print chr$(13,10)

    leave
    ret 4
    exit
```

Comment: Where is the code of `datetonum`?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I can include it - however I don't know that it's necessary to see to accomplish what I'm trying to do. It just converts one of the dates from dates into a unique 32 bit number, and stores it in EAX

Comment: Well, it's necessary to include that code into your question for _not being closed_ because of a missing [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would highly suggest it.

Comment: @zx485 Alright, just edited my original post. it's in there now.

Comment: @zx485: note that you can write `[mcve]` in a comment, and it will expand to [mcve].

Comment: `lea ECX, ra` / `mov [ECX + nDates], EAX`.  The sum of two memory addresses is not going to be useful...  I don't see a single specific question here, or any description of what doesn't work or what you found with a debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry for any confusion in my original post. I simply want to put the value from EAX into the first element of my "ra" array. I'm just not comfortable enough with assembly syntax/memory structure to know how to do it. In C++ it would be something like array[i] = value;

Comment: So you didn't want anything to do with `nDates`?  I thought you were trying to use its value as an index (but you actually used its address).  Use `mov [ra], eax` to do a 32-bit store to the address labelled with `ra`.  See links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more links, including one that describes the available addressing modes.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks Peter. I tried mov [ra], eax. For some reason it crashes my program. I am really not enjoying this assembly class!!

Comment: Crashes on that instruction??  If that's the case, something is seriously wrong (like you're running 16-bit code in real mode and segment registers are wrong???)  You should always be able to write any value you want to a fixed address in your data section.  Or do you mean it crashes later on some other instruction?  Use a debugger!!

Comment: @PeterCordes it crashes on that instruction. Do you recommend a certain debugger to use with MASM32?

Comment: @tay1392: no idea, I don't even use Windows.  I use gdb, which is more designed for C, but is usable for asm.  It can show a register window that highlights which ones changed while single-stepping.  (see notes in the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)  So you could use the cygwin or mingw version of gdb, I think, but I doubt many Windows users would recommend that.

Comment: Are you sure `ra` is in the read-write data section, not somehow being put in with read-only data?

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are stored in an array, and you want to use another array to store the dates converted to numbers, you will need at least one loop. You can use index registers (ESI, EDI) to point to both arrays, then use one register to read the value from one array, and the other register to move the value into the other array.

Let's imagine you already have next 3 procedures :

- `num2date` : converts a num in EAX back into a date (the opposite of `datetonum`). This date is stored in a variable `date` that is declared like this : `date BYTE "DD-MMM-AAAA"`.
- `bubble_sort` : sorts the numbers in array `ra`.
- `transfer_date` : takes the 11 bytes of variable `date` and move them into the position pointed by `ESI` (`ESI` is pointing somewhere inside array `dates`).

This could be the logic of your code :

```
start:
;▼ NEXT LOOP CONVERTS ALL DATES TO NUMBERS ▼
    lea ESI, dates      ;POINTER TO ARRAY "DATES".
    lea EDI, ra         ;POINTER TO ARRAY "RA".
    mov ECX, 5          ;LENGTH OF ARRAY "DATES".
dates2numbers:
    push ECX ESI EDI    ;PRESERVE REGISTERS.
    mov  EAX, [ESI]     ;CURRENT DATE.
    push EAX
    call datetonum      ;CONVERT CURRENT DATE TO A NUMBER.
    pop  EAX            ;GET THE NUMBER.
    pop  EDI ESI ECX    ;RESTORE REGISTERS.
    mov  [EDI], EAX     ;STORE NUMBER IN "RA".
    add  ESI, 12        ;NEXT ITEM IN ARRAY "DATES" (12 BYTES EACH).
    add  EDI, 4         ;NEXT ITEM IN ARRAY "RA" (4 BYTES EACH).
    loop dates2numbers

    call bubble_sort    ;◄■■■ SORT ARRAY "RA".

;▼ NEXT LOOP CONVERTS ALL NUMBERS TO DATES ▼
    lea ESI, dates      ;POINTER TO ARRAY "DATES".
    lea EDI, ra         ;POINTER TO ARRAY "RA".
    mov ECX, 5          ;LENGTH OF ARRAY "RA".
numbers2dates:
    push ECX ESI EDI    ;PRESERVE REGISTERS.
    mov  EAX, [EDI]     ;CURRENT NUMBER.
    call num2date       ;CONVERTS EAX TO A DATE IN VARIABLE "DATE".
                        ;VARIABLE "DATE" LOOKS LIKE THIS : DATE BYTE "DD-MMM-AAAA"
                        ;"NUM2DATE" SHOULD PRESERVE ESI AND RESTORE IT
                        ;BECAUSE "TRANSFER_DATE" WILL NEED IT.
    call transfer_date  ;TRANSFER CONTENT OF VARIABLE "DATE" INTO THE
                        ;ARRAY "DATES" AT THE POSITION ESI IS POINTING TO.
    pop  EDI ESI ECX    ;RESTORE REGISTERS.
    add  ESI, 12        ;NEXT ITEM IN ARRAY "DATES" (12 BYTES EACH).
    add  EDI, 4         ;NEXT ITEM IN ARRAY "RA" (4 BYTES EACH).
    loop numbers2dates
```

Comment: `call datetonum` + `pop eax`: as the return value is in `eax`, this doesn't look like good idea. Also OP is using `ret 4` to pop the argument, so you don't need to `pop`.

Comment: So, @tay1392, I guess my answer was not useful or too much complicated, was it? I added comments on the right of each instruction to explain it. I wanted to tell you the logic to convert all dates to numbers, sort them, and convert them back to dates.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez It was helpful Jose. I appreciate you taking the time to do that. It was a little complicated just because I am not comfortable with assembly at all really. But your comments and logic make sense. Didn't end up getting my assignment working, but oh well. Thanks again.